# Нужна ли запятая или тире после "подарила"?

Tags: пунктуация

Сказала:

*Что ты, милый,

Тебе я подарила

В Тайване очень модный,

Элитнейший массаж!*

Comment: Запятой точно не надо. И правильно "на Тайване", поскольку это остров, а страны такой даже и нету.

Comment: А точно должно было быть "в Тайване", а не "в Таиланде"?

Comment: спасибо за ответы. думаю, что и правда - в Тайланде.

Answer (score 1):

Спросил: "Что это было,

Взяла бы и добила,

Когда плясала лихо, войдя в такой кураж"

Сказала: "Что ты, **милый,**

Тебе я подарила —

В Тайване очень модный, элитнейший массаж!"

Источник: https://poembook.ru/poem/2145374

Если бы это была проза, то звучало бы так: *Что ты, милый, тебе я подарила 
 **очень модный в Тайване, элитнейший массаж**!*

В стихотворении использована **инверсия** и  поэтому поставлено  **интонационное тире** (чтобы избежать неверного  сочетания *подарила в Тайване*).  Также может обозначать **неожиданный переход**.

Запятая не подойдет, так как первое определение  запятыми по правилам не обособляется.